# Moisture sensitivity for SMD LEDs

Tags: led, surface-mount

I was adding some small components to a Digikey order, just because I couldn't stand to pay the shipping costs for the single item I really needed.  I just received my order to find that the SMD LEDs are moisture sensitive.

I hadn't bothered to think about this issue, mainly because I really wanted SMD LEDs on my board because they look cool.  :)  After googling, I've read that either "most" SMD LEDs are moisture-sensitive, or that *all* are.  I haven't found any that specifically state that they aren't, and Digikey's search tool doesn't have this as a selectable parameter.

So my questions are:

1. does any manufacturer make a SMD LED that isn't moisture-sensitive, i.e. does not need to be sealed and / or mounted soon after opening the package, and
2. are there any other cool looking LED options, besides a T1 through-hole package?  :)

Comment: I've soldered hundreds of LEDs, both by hand and in our little reflow oven. I'm not aware of any having failed during the soldering process.

Comment: Ad. 2) http://www.conrad.nl/medias/global/ce/7000_7999/7200/7270/7271/727164_BB_00_FB.EPS_250.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For hobbyist work, it really doesn't matter that much. If you are hand-soldering them, just be careful to not apply too much heat, or for too long.

If you plan to reflow your boards, you might want to pre-bake your LEDs to drive out any accumulated moisture, and that isn't difficult to do. There will usually be instructions in the datasheet.

Comment: Thank you for the tips!  I have read about baking other moisture-sensitive SMDs before, but not LEDs.  I'll definitely check the datasheet.